# Why tel:* links don't work on ios?

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I added this to config.xml

```
<access origin="*"/>
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<allow-intent href="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="tel:*"/>
<allow-navigation href="mailto:*"/>
<allow-navigation href="data:*"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
```

And this to index.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

When I'm clicking to a link like that: `<a href="tel:+1234567">Call!</a>` nothing happens on the ios (on the android it works well).

If I change my config.xml to:

```
<access origin="//*"/>
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<allow-intent href="//*"/>
<allow-navigation href="//*"/>
<allow-navigation href="tel:*"/>
<allow-navigation href="mailto:*"/>
<allow-navigation href="data:*"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
```

It calls, but ajax requests to server stop working.

Comment: Does it work if you use `tel://` instead of `tel:`?

Comment: Yeah, should just be `tel:+15555555555`. No slashes.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: I still cannot get this to work on iOS with Ionic3... works fine on Android - tried many solutions here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just remove allow-navigation

```
<allow-navigation href="tel:*"/>
<allow-navigation href="mailto:*"/>
```

I don't why ,but it work!

cordova-ios@4+wkwebview will get the navigation filter first to  respond for the url,and **do nothing**!!

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine/pull/20

Comment: removing `<allow-navigation href="*" />` is what worked for me.

Comment: Removing the allow-navigation tel:* and mailto:* makes android stop working.
@Iwrestledabearonce. answer worked for me.