# Tel:* and Sms:* links don't work on ios under cordova in phonegap?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

My app uses href: tel links and it worked correctly, when I first released it a year ago.

I used allow-intent in my config.xml:

```
  <access origin="*"/>
  <access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
  <access origin="sms:*" launch-external="yes"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist"/>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
```

But now freshly compiled app for iOS with the same config doesnt work with href: tel links. Just nothing happens.

As said here: cordova - [Why tel:* links don't work on ios? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38310197/why-tel-links-dont-work-on-ios)
I need to remove allow-navigation from config.xml. But I dont have it there.

What is the proper configuration to make it work under new cordova?

EDIT: other external links and sms:* dont work as well, but on iPad tel:* link offers to copy number (expected behaivior)

Comment: Do you know which CLI is being used to build the app? which cordova-ios platform version is being used?

Comment: As far as I know phonegap.build.com is on 4.3.0 of Cordova

Comment: Why don't you check? That information is on the build page

Comment: Didnt know this :( 

`PhoneGap (iOS / Android / Windows)` => 
`cli-6.3.0 (4.2.0 / 5.2.1 / 4.4.1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the access origin for tel and sms

`<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<access origin="sms:*" launch-external="yes"/>`

Also you can try setting the CLI version to 6.4.0, there has been some changes in how the intent and navigation filter worked in cordova-ios 4.3.0 and you are using 4.2.0

`<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.4.0" />`

But I've seen a bug report about tel links working when the app was locally compiled with Cordova but not working on Phonegap Build, so it might be a bug there.

Comment: I didnt remove access origin, I set preference for cli-6.4.0

Comment: This what? removing the access tags? then you are using a very old Cordova/Phonegap version, the way of making them work is to use allow-intent instead

Comment: Mine doesn't even build on Phonegap when i upgrade to CLI 6.4.0 it has an error code 70.... the same when its 6.5.0

Comment: @Benyaman you should ask on phonegap build forums about that https://forums.adobe.com/community/phonegap/build

Answer (score 0):

Comment both the below `allow-navigation` and `access origin launch-external` sets of links from config.xml (Manifest) for the tel:*, sms:* and mailto:* links to work on ionic cordova or phonegap with android and ios:

```
<allow-navigation href="tel:*" />
<allow-navigation href="mailto:*" />

<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />
<access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="yes" />
```

Maybe, this is so because the latest Cordova and Phonegap versions are designed to use the below set of `allow-intent` links instead of `allow-navigation` and `access origin launch-external` links:

```
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also an issue with inAppBrowser 5.0.0 and Cordova 11.

The fix is [in GitHub](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/pull/881) so the solution is to use that version:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/
```

Call the telephone link like this:

```
onclick="window.open('tel:00000000', '_blank', 'hidden=yes'); return false;"
```

Note that it only seems to work if the number contains no spaces.