# Cordova phone links do not work on iPhone X

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap

Phone dialler is open on iPhone 6+. But message app is open on iPhone X. I have used
`<allow-navigation href="tel:*"/>` in cofig.xml. But it does not work.

Comment: Have you tried https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/call-number? I had some issue on the past and this worked for me. Make sure you try it on real device

Comment: According to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41750541/tel-and-sms-links-dont-work-on-ios-under-cordova-in-phonegap) you should remove the `allow-navigation` option and instead use `allow-intent`.